# Connecting Oracle remote database using instantclient_11_2 and VBScript

Tags: oracle, vbscript

the operating system is windows 10 64bit

I have configured on `c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32` the new user DSN using driver Oracle in `instantclient_11_2` for connect remote Oracle database

[image]

the connection is successfull

[image]

now i tried connection on VBscript file but the return is an error

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

how to do resolve this?

```
   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
   cn.Open "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_11_2}; " & _
           "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
           "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
           "(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521))" & _
           "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX))); uid=XXX;pwd=XX;"
  
   cn.CommandTimeout = 10000
   
   cn.Close()
   Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Are running `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` in 32-bit mode, i.e `%systemroot%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe`? If you just call `wscript.exe` it will default to the 64-bit version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Setting up an Oracle ODBC Driver and Data Source](https://tensix.com/2012/06/setting-up-an-oracle-odbc-driver-and-data-source/)

[Last version 64-bit ODAC 12.2c Release 1 (12.2.0.1.1) for Windows x64](https://download.oracle.com/otn/other/ole-oo4o/ODAC122011_x64.zip?xd_co_f=037d6fe3-114c-41f0-bc66-b49636779b77)

[Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/)

```
   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
   cn.Open "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12home1}; " & _
           "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
           "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
           "(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521))" & _
           "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX))); uid=XXX;pwd=XX;"
  
   cn.CommandTimeout = 10000
   
   cn.Close()
   Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm not sure how any of this answers the question, the OP has explained they setup their DSN using the correct architecture version of `odbcad32.exe`, so their issue isn't the connection. Maybe you are suggesting not using a DSN and hard coding the connection, but that doesn't explain why they can't access the DSN.

Comment: Thank you so much mr Hamamelis, now working!